# Setting different frequency policies for sibling cores with SMT

Tags: cpu, hyper-threading

On a processor that supports simultaneous multithreading, of which I no longer have any for testing, what would happen if only one or some of a physical core's logical core has a frequency policy different from the rest (e.g. set by `cpupower`)?

For example, suppose I am using a 4-core processor with 2-way SMT, where logical cores 0 and 1 belong to physical core 0, logical 2 and 3 belong to physical core 1, and so on. What would happen if I were to limit LC0's maximum frequency to, say, 2.0 GHz, and LC1's to 3.0 GHz, and then max out the CPU? I heard somewhere that physical cores can only ever have one frequency at any point in time, so my guess is that only one setting will override the other (e.g. maybe the later setting, or whichever is lower/higher). Even then, what would happen if one LC's frequency range is set to be entirely non-overlapping with its sibling(s) (e.g. 1.0 to 2.0 GHz for LC0, and 3.0 to 4.0 GHz for LC1)? What would be the effective frequency range for PC0? Would such a strange governor setting cause it to flip-flop?

Although this question is not necessarily specific to `cpupower`, I am not sure to what extent it would depend on the behaviour of the tool used to set the policy (it could be aware of SMT and error out upon noticing the strange request) versus the governor itself or something. Note that I have no practical use for doing such a thing. I'm just curious about what would happen.

Comment: Do you have a command that would work under Windows to test this? I'm curious about this but I would expect the core speed to be set to whatever setting was *last* applied, or possibly use the setting only when that particular hyperthread is running on that core. I have a hyperthreaded quad-core, but it shows only four core clock frequencies rather than eight so perhaps you can only set the *core* speed rather than the hyperthreaded "core" speed.

Comment: I don't really use Windows, so I don't know what equivalent there is for that. :c
And yeah, I had that guess, too, just no way to test it at the moment. I have seen `cpupower` report different active frequencies for different logical cores presumably on the same physical core, but they were all within a tiny amount of each other, probably due to polling timings.